# Avoid line wrapping in merged documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, font-size, word-wrap

I have this program I wrote to create bin labels for my company's warehouse. Each season, we print several hundred bin labels.

The problem I have is that at the font size used in the template, sometimes the lines wrap, and then things are harder to read or don't fit on the labels, etc. So I end up going through the resulting merge document, and manually reducing font sizes of individual lines where line wrapping is happening. It's a real pain in the butt.

What I really want to do is, for a given field's content, set the font size to the maximum size that is equal to or less than the font size used in the template, that prevents line wrapping. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish that.

This can't possibly be an uncommon problem? Surely there's some obvious solution that I'm missing?

If nothing else, I guess I can probably use a dictionary that maps line lengths to font sizes, that I just come up with by trial and error. But it seems like there must be some better way that isn't jumping out at me, that someone with more experience with the Word interop might be able to point me at.

Here's my code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a mail merge document from a template and some data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="templatePath">
    ///   The path (including the pathname) of the template file to open.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="mergedFilePath">
    ///   The path (including the pathname) to save the resulting merged file to
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="mergeData">
    ///   The data to use for the merge - An array of Dictionaries that map strings to strings; 
    ///   the keys are template field names and the values are the field values to use.
    /// </param>
    public void Create(string templatePath, string mergedFilePath, DataTable mergeData){
        Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        // start up word and start reporting progress
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
        ProgressStarted("Creating merge document..", mergeData.Rows.Count);  

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {

            try {
                // copy the template file to the target file (for the sake of the layout properties)
                if (File.Exists(mergedFilePath)) {
                    File.Delete(mergedFilePath);
                }
                File.Copy(templatePath, mergedFilePath);

                // open the template, the target document, and a (new) temporary document (that will never be saved)
                Word.Document templateDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(templatePath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
                Word.Document mergedDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(mergedFilePath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
                Word.Document tempDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

                // clear out the target document (to start with)
                mergedDoc.Activate();
                mergedDoc.Content.Text = "";

                // iterate through the rows in mergeData
                int rowNum = 0;
                while (rowNum < mergeData.Rows.Count) {

                    // copy the template document into the temporary document
                    tempDoc.Content.FormattedText = templateDoc.Content.FormattedText;

                    // replace the text in the merge fields in the temporary document
                    foreach (Word.Field mergeField in tempDoc.Fields) {

                        // the field text comes in the format " MERGEFIELD  {fieldname} " (without the quotes or curly braces)
                        Word.Range rngFieldCode = mergeField.Code;
                        String[] fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text.Trim().Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // null parameter means "use whitespace as a delimiter"
                        if (rowNum < mergeData.Rows.Count) {
                            if (fieldText[0] == "MERGEFIELD") {
                                string fieldName = fieldText[1];
                                string fieldValue = mergeData.Rows[rowNum][fieldName].ToString();

                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("field: {0}  value: {1}", fieldName, fieldValue));

                                mergeField.Select();
                                wordApp.Selection.TypeText(fieldValue);     // type the value into the field
                            }
                            else if (fieldText[0] == "NEXT") {
                                rowNum += 1;
                                ProgressMade(rowNum);           // (invoked progress display update)
                                mergeField.Code.Text = "";      // blank out where it says "<<next record>>"
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            mergeField.Code.Text = "";          // blank out the remaining fields after we run out of data
                        }
                    }

                    // add the contents of the temporary document into the target document
                    mergedDoc.Content.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                    wordApp.Selection.InsertXML(tempDoc.Content.XML);
                    tempDoc.Content.Text = "";

                    // if we're not done yet, insert a page break
                    if (rowNum < mergeData.Rows.Count) {
                        mergedDoc.Content.Select();
                        wordApp.Selection.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                        wordApp.Selection.InsertBreak();
                        wordApp.Selection.InsertXML(tempDoc.Content.XML);
                    }
                }

                // delete the last empty paragraph (hopefully this will eliminate any dangling empty page)
                Word.Paragraph emptyPara = null;
                foreach (Word.Paragraph para in mergedDoc.Paragraphs) {
                    if (para.Range.Text.Trim() == String.Empty) {
                        emptyPara = para;
                    }
                }
                if (emptyPara != null) {
                    emptyPara.Range.Select();
                    wordApp.Selection.Delete();
                }

                // save the merged document
                mergedDoc.SaveAs(mergedFilePath);

                //mergedApp.Documents.Open(mergedFilePath);

                // close and release the documents
                ((Word._Document)tempDoc).Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
                ((Word._Document)mergedDoc).Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
                ((Word._Document)templateDoc).Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tempDoc);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mergedDoc);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(templateDoc);
                tempDoc = null;
                mergedDoc = null;
                templateDoc = null;
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("error: " + exc.Message);
                Error(exc); // (invoked error dialog)
            }
            finally {
                // quit the application and and perform garbage collection
                ((Word._Application)wordApp.Application).Quit();
                wordApp = null;
                GC.Collect();
                // signal that we're done
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Signaling progress finished");
                ProgressFinished(); 
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Making this a comment because I'm not sure, but I think you could use `System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(fieldValue. <The font you're currently using in the Word doc.>)` Then if the result is bigger than the field, retry with a smaller font until it fits.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: MeasureString is a thought. I'll have to use trial and error, I guess, to figure out how wide the field is, but it seems like it should work. Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: Just as an observation, if the total line length does not vary vary much from record to record, you could consider putting the line in a table cell formatted with .FitText = true. Word should then expand/squeeze the text. It's not pretty, and it's really not pretty if Word ends up expanding/squeezing a lot, , but it may be enough.